# How do I search for a file extension located in the desktop and change their file types?

Tags: vbscript

```
User = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName ' gets username
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Recurse objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\" & User & "\Desktop\") ' searches for file extensions in the desktop

Sub Recurse(objFolder)
    Dim objFile, objSubFolder

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name)) = "mymom" Then ' if a file extension is mymom (just a test)
            objFSO.MoveFile objFile.Name objFile.Name & ".ayy" ' changes the file extension to ayy (another test)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

When I do this, I get an error saying, "Expected end of statement." However, I do not know where to add the end statement. What I am trying to do is I am trying to let the script search the Desktop for all files with a specific file extension (in this case, I want to search for a file extension with .mymom) Then, I want to change the file extension with .ayy (This is the struggle part) I don't know if my code is wrong, or if it's just the end statement part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the error, probably because you have missed a `,` between the source and destination file paths in the `moveFile` method

Use this code:

```
strFinalName = replace(objFile.name, "."&objFso.getExtensionname(objFile.name),".ayy")
objFSO.MoveFile objFile.Name,strFinalName
```